# Finding the next free value with LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Below is a very simple Entity class and data sample.

```
Public Class MyTable 
   Public int Id { get; set; } 
   Public string Classification { get; set; }
   Public string Description { get; set; }
}

// Sample data :
context.MyTable.Add(new MyTable('10.000', '...'));
context.MyTable.Add(new MyTable('10.001', '...'));
context.MyTable.Add(new MyTable('10.002', '...'));
context.MyTable.Add(new MyTable('11.000', '...'));
context.MyTable.Add(new MyTable('11.001', '...'));
context.MyTable.Add(new MyTable('11.002', '...'));
context.MyTable.Add(new MyTable('11.003', '...'));
context.MyTable.Add(new MyTable('11.004', '...'));
context.MyTable.Add(new MyTable('12.000', '...'));
```

I neet to return the next free *Classification* value for a given input value.

For example:

- '10.000' - Should return '10.003'
- '11.000' - Should return '11.005'

For the first example above, input value is '10.000' so by stepping one by one, we check if value exists or not. Whenever value already exists in DB we continue searching for n+1.

What is the best way to proceed with LINQ ?

Comment: Can there be holes within one number?. I.e. `10.000, 10.001, 10.003`. Here `10.002` would be the next free value. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: If you can use a table of valid values to compare against then you can do a not exists query.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690651/how-do-i-populate-a-table-that-contains-only-an-identity-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there were no missing values within a whole number (e.g. `10.000`), then you could get the highest one with:

```
string input = "10.000";
string nextFree = input;
string max = mySet
    .Where(x => x.Classification.StartsWith(input.Substring(0, 3)) // I.e. "10."
    .Select(x => x.Classification)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Max();
if (max != null) {
    decimal maxNum = Decimal.Parse(max);
    nextFree = (maxNum + 0.001m).ToString("0.000");
}
```

But if there are missing values in between:

```
string input = "10.000"; // Must always be a value with .000
var classifications = mySet
    .Where(x => x.Classification.StartsWith(input.Substring(0, 3))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Classification)
    .Select(x => x.Classification)
    .ToList();
decimal nextNum = Decimal.Parse(input);
foreach (string classification in classifications)
{
    decimal n = Decimal.Parse(classification);
    if (n > nextNum) {
        break; // Found the next free value.
    }
    nextNum += 0.001m;
}    
string nextFree = nextNum.ToString("0.000");
```

Comment: Good job! I'll try that tomorrow and keep you informed.