# How do I populate a table that contains only an identity column?

Tags: sql-server

Consider the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Numbers]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How do I populate it?

If I add a column (`text nchar(20)` say)  then I can populate it with:

```
insert into numbers (text) values ('')
```

but if there are no other columns besides the identity, what do I do?

```
insert into numbers ( ) values ( )
```

This throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I want to use this for a find the missing sequence number problem.

Comment: I don't think you should have a table with one (1) column (`Normalisation`), See [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Why not use a Tally Table if you're trying to identify missing numbers?

Comment: @Lamu thankyou. I looked it up athttps://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/benjamin/2018/02/06/sql-tip-the-tally-table/

Comment: L A R N U. There is no M.

Comment: ah, my eyesight, sorry @Larnu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `DEFAULT VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even you can use [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable ON;  
GO 
INSERT INTO YourTable (IdentityColumn) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable OFF;
```

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Numbers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

DECLARE @Start INT=1;
DECLARE @End INT=100;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Numbers] ON;
WITH Gen AS (
    SELECT @Start AS Num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Num + 1 FROM Gen WHERE Num + 1 <= @End
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Numbers] (Id)
SELECT Num 
FROM Gen
OPTION (maxrecursion 100);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Numbers] OFF;

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Numbers];
```